# Python try except in while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
while True:
    print "Unesite ime datoteke kojoj zelite pristupiti."
    try:
        ime = raw_input("")
        printaj = open(ime, "r")
        print "Ovo su informacije ucenika %s." % (ime)
        print printaj.read()
    except:
        print "Datoteka %s ne postoji." % (ime)
    printaj.close()
```

This program is supposed to look for a file, open and read it if it exists.

So I open program, try to look for a file lets say under name "John" but it doesn't exist so program closes even its in a while loop. When I look for a file and it exists, it's information is printed and my program works as intended.

From there I can look for a file that doesn't exist and it prints out `Datoteka %s ne postoji.` like I wanted. 
So problem here is the first file name I look up for in a program.
If its correct than good... program will function from there.

But if its wrong ... program just closes and you have to open program again.

Comment: Don't use naked `except` clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the file does not exist, it cannot be opened. The variable `printaj` is not initialized. `printaj.close()` causes a `NameError`, and the program crashes. Possible solutions:

- Move `printaj.close()` into the `try` block of your code, just after `printaj.read()`
- Use `with open(ime, "r") as printaj`, it will close the file automatically (kindly suggested in the comments)

Comment: or use `with open(ime, "r") as printaj:` then it handles the close for you.

Comment: Better yet, use a `with` block.

Comment: Thank you.... just moving printaj.close() into try block did the trick..